# Ionic App Live Reload on Android Device Fails: connection to the server was unsuccessful

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to run my ionic app in a live reload state using the following command.

```
ionic run android --device -l
```

I get a black screen and then the error "connection to the server was unsuccessful(http://my_ip_here:8100)

I tried adding the following to get my live reload to work.

flags:

```
 --livereload-host
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I also don't know if I should be running it with the USB attached to my device or if I should be remotely connecting to my laptop dev server. If so, I have tried to have my phone on the same wifi as my laptop and I haven't had any success.

Comment: Use a USB when running on device. Perhaps add this to config: `<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>`

Answer (score -1):

coonect via USB. Check for devices attached or not by command `adb devices`on cmd. It will show all your devices attached . If your device is showing then use command `ionic run android` ,this command will build app and install app on your device automatically.

Comment: The issue is not running the app. The standard "ionic run android" works. The live reload is what doesn't work. I need to get the live reload to work.

Comment: @DrewGallagher, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error with my home WIFI but not at my office (same devices). It can be an issue with the router configuration.

I could run livereload by connecting my laptop to my phone Hotspot. The steps to do this is:

- Share your android connection
- Connect your computer to your phone connection
- Run : `ionic run android -l`
- Choose the IP address conform to your phone